# Recursion logic is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I have a method that returns an object that returns `referrals of a individual`

```
function getReferredUsers(userId) {
    const usersMap = {
        a : ['b', 'c'],
        b: ['d', 'e'],
        d: ['f', 'g']
    };


    return usersMap[userId] || [];
}
```

So, in the example `a directly referred b and c`. While `b directly referred d and e` and so on.

so `d and e` becomes `indirect referrals` for `a`. `f,g` are indirect for `a` as `d is also an indirect` for `a`.

**For direct we get 3 points for indirect we get 2.**

We need to calculate total points for `a`.

I tried

```
var _opSum = 0;
function getTotalReferralBonus(userId, bonus) {
    if(bonus === 0)
        return 0;
    let directUsers = getReferredUsers(userId);
    if(directUsers.length > 0) {
        for(let user of directUsers) {
            _opSum = getTotalReferralBonus(user, bonus -1) + bonus;      
        }
    }else {
        _opSum += getTotalReferralBonus(userId, bonus -1);
    }

    return _opSum;    
}
```

**But it does not work.**

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

Total points that `a` would get is  `3 + 3 (for b,c) + 2 + 2 (for d,e through b) + 1 + 1 (for f,g through d through b)` = `12`

Comment: how is `d` going to `a`? please add the wanted result.

Comment: I think `_opSum` needs to be a *local* variable of the recursive function. Otherwise, that assignment in the `for ... of` loop will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: @NinaScholz Please see the update

Answer (score 2):

You need a local variable `_opSum` and you need to get all bonusses from the nested `Id`.

```js
function getReferredUsers(userId) {
  const usersMap = {
    a: ['b', 'c'],
    b: ['d', 'e'],
    d: ['f', 'g']
  };
  return usersMap[userId] || [];
}

function getTotalReferralBonus(userId, bonus) {
  var _opSum = 0; // local variable
  if (bonus === 0) return 0;
  let directUsers = getReferredUsers(userId);
  if (directUsers.length > 0) {
    for (let user of directUsers) {
      _opSum += getTotalReferralBonus(user, bonus - 1) + bonus; // add all instead of assignment
    }
  } else {
    _opSum += getTotalReferralBonus(userId, bonus - 1);
  }
  return _opSum;
}

console.log(getTotalReferralBonus('a', 3));
```